# How to solve Error 26: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified in production environment?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2012

I have a strange error in production environment BUT not in develop environment. 
In my develop environment, with Visual studio 2010, i can connect without problem to Sql Server 2012. 
When i copy my Windows Form app to others PC in the same network, i get an "Error 26:Error Locating Server/Instance Specified".

The same application worked good with an old database instance with Sql Server 2008.
I don't know what to check and where to start!

EDIT: Another strange behavior is that it works good if i use   a code like this

```
conn.Open()

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

But stop to work if i open a form with a datagridview, a dataset and a BindingSource !

Comment: How about the connection string? Are you referencing localhost or . as the host name?

Comment: This is my connection string : Data Source=192.168.x.y;Initial Catalog=dbname;User id=username;Password=password

Comment: Did you check that the sql server can take connections from other computers?

Comment: Yes, i can connect from others computer, also with that application. Only when i use a form with a datagridview, dataset and bindingsource, i get the error 26 !!!!

Comment: Could you show us the full code you're using when you try it with a DataGridView, DataSet and BindingSource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx) blog post has detailed information about error 26.

From the post:

> In a word, the reason that we get this error message is the client
>   stack could not receive SSRP response UDP packet from SQL Browser.
>   It's easy to isolate the issue. Here are the steps:
>
> 1. Make sure your server name is correct, e.g., no typo on the name.
> 2. Make sure your instance name is correct and there is actually such an instance on your target machine. [Update: Some application converts \ to . If you are not sure about your application, please try both Server\Instance and Server\\Instance in your connection string]
> 3. Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be resolve correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always true).
> 4. Make sure SQL Browser service is running on the server.
> 5. If firewall is enabled on the server, you need to put sqlbrowser.exe and/or UDP port 1434 into exception.
>
> Once you are done the steps, you should not see this error message
>   anymore. You may still fail to connect your SQL server, but error
>   message should be different and you have a different issue now.
>   [Update: If it still fails, you may replace server\instance with
>   tcp:server\instance and/or np:server\instance and see if it succeeds
>   with either TCP or NP protocol. That way, you can isolate the issue a
>   little bit. ]