# Error 26: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified in production environment - SQL server 2014 wpf wcf

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, wcf

I realise that this problem has been raised many times and a number of suggestions for how to fix it have been made, but despite following many of these suggestions, including all the one's listed here: [How to solve Error 26: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified in production environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340531/how-to-solve-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified-in-production-en)

and here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

and turning the firewall off I still can't resolve my problem. I have a WCF service that I am running via Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. The service talks to a database I have set up in SQL Server Management studio. The server, database and service are all running locally on a windows 8 laptop. I connect the to service via a WPF application on the same laptop. This is a development version hence running it all on the laptop. This works fine on one laptop but when I transfer everything over to another laptop I get the error: 26 issue. Both laptops are the same (same make/model/spec/OS).

The machine that works has the following connection string (where laptop-name is the name of my laptop and DBname is the name of the database):

```
<add name="AirportTaxiAccountsPackageDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=laptop-name\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBname;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

NB:the set up details within SQL server management studio are: server name is laptop-name\SQLEXPRESS and the connection is laptop-name\user-nameA

The machine that doesn't work has the following connection string:

```
<add name="AirportTaxiAccountsPackageDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=laptop-name\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBname;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

NB: the set up details within SQL server management studio on this computer are: server-name is laptop-name\SQLEXPRESS and the connection is laptop-name\user-nameB

This connection string was set up on the second laptop by creating and testing the connection from within VS via the database connection wizard. when I test the connection via the wizard it works fine, it's only when I connect to it via my wpf application that a connection problem occurs.

One last thing, I checked the service is runnning correctly on the second laptop, it is fine and I can connect to it, the problem occurs when I try to access the database. the process is run service using host, connect to service via WPF, connect to database > error 26

Any ideas?

**Edited again** 
i've set up a test client which can access the service, I get the same error which is the error 26 error locating server/instance specified

**RESOLVED**
I was hard coding the database configuration details again via a class within the service rather than talking to the configuration file!! I am a dufus but now I know better :)

Answer (score 0):

I had hard coded the database connection string into configuration class within the service which was overwriting the database connection string in the app.config file *blush*